# How to Remove previous Info Window while clicking on another marker in google maps Ionic/Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How to Remove previous **Info Window**  while clicking on another marker in google maps **Ionic/Angular**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        public activeWindow:any; //1).It's a global value when you click on first marker this value will be null or undefined.
    //2). Clicking on second marker or another it has previous marker information.
        .....
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
              if (this.activeWindow) { this.activeWindow.close();}    // 1).First time this value won't satisfy the condition.
   // 2).Second time this condition satisfies and close the previous window.           
              this.activeWindow = infoWindow; // Saving marker information in global declaration value(i.e. activeWindow)
              infoWindow.open(self.map, marker);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//assuming you have a map called 'map'
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({position:latlng1, map:map});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click',
    function(){
        infowindow.close();//hide the infowindow
        infowindow.setContent('Marker #1');//update the content for this marker
        infowindow.open(map, marker1);//"move" the info window to the clicked marker and open it
    }
);
var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(10,10);
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({position:latlng2, map:map});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click',
    function(){
        infowindow.close();//hide the infowindow
        infowindow.setContent('Marker #2');//update the content for this marker
        infowindow.open(map, marker2);//"move" the info window to the clicked marker and open it
    }
);
```

Comment: The above solution is for two markers only. if we have multiple markers We can't use  marker1 and marker2.....so on.   can you please help me with multiple marker solution. Thanks

Comment: You may have multiple markers but here we a single infowindow object. We need to check that object is available. If yes, Obviously we close it or else we can open a new window.